# what is best practice for creating a complex API with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a client that I do a lot of work for. They need the same thing or close to it on every project. We basically create, update and retrieve user data from the server. Normally I create a new rails project because there is always some small thing that is different about each project and it's usually a matter of adding a value to the model or tweaking the way the controller does things based on the application that they are building on the client side.

What I would like to do is create one rails app to rule them all. My thought is to have a single model. Let's just call this model User for now.

in my routs file I am thinking I should do something like this

```
match '/create-fbuser/:app_id'  =>    'Main#update_user'
```

Each time we have a new project I will just have the client side developer use a different "app_id" once this param is inspected in the Main controller would it be best practice to pass off the params to a second controller that is basically set up to do the custom functionality for that particular project ?

I've not done anything like this before and just wondering if this is the best way or if there is some "rails" convention I should follow that would better handle this type of thing.

Basically Main controller would act as the main "facade" and it would pass off work to other controllers. If this is the best way I'd like some idea of exactly how this should be done.